# How to find the NPM code in Azure app Service Linux

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I am using an azure release pipeline to deploy the code onto the azure app service in linux and the app service log show that the zip is deployed and I use the `npm run start` command and notice that I see the following error on the

```
2020-10-09T23:56:28.471358369Z npm ERR! path /home/site/wwwroot/package.json
2020-10-09T23:56:28.474154087Z npm ERR! errno -2
2020-10-09T23:56:28.484295653Z npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/site/wwwroot/package.json'
2020-10-09T23:56:28.485287759Z npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
2020-10-09T23:56:28.486203565Z npm ERR! enoent
2020-10-09T23:56:28.568838301Z npm timing npm Completed in 338ms
2020-10-09T23:56:28.570373811Z
2020-10-09T23:56:28.571579218Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

This indicated the `package.json` is not found but I am not sure how to assign the app service a specific directory and where does the code get pushed to in app deployment

Comment: Can you show us the file structure under your wwwroot path?

Comment: From the error log, the command is looking for the `package.json` file in the wwwroot path. In azure app service, you could add **scm** to site URL(e.g. `https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/`), then you could navigate to site folder  to check the files in the wwwroot folder. You need to make sure that the file is under wwwroot folder.